# Problem with web3.eth.personal.ecRecover

Tags: go-ethereum, ecrecover, typescript

I'm using web3 v1.0 beta33 ethereum packages to do some signing and address recovery in a javascript/Angular5 app. I picked this version because I didn't see this function in 0.2x web3 versions' documentation. They only mention an "ecrecover" when referring to Solidity, which I'm not using, so I thought I had to be able to get to it from a v1.x web3 environment. I invoke the function with:`web3.eth.personal.ecRecover`. Compiling results in the error:`....component.ts(77,38): error TS2339: Property 'ecRecover' does not exist on type 'Personal'.` I previously had problems ("does not exist", expecting 0 args but got 3) invoking `eth.personal.unlockAccount`, where I had to add some argument info into its declaration in `node_modules/web3/types.d.ts`, and add "personal" to the list of "--rpcapi" options in the "geth" invocation to get everything to work. I think I matched any edits I did for unlockAccount in trying to fix ecRecover. I thought I was still in the app's web3/typescript world from the look of the error, but I now think it may be the web3 versions that are being used. In the app, I have `"web3": "1.0.0-beta.33"` in its `package.json`. But in the `geth` I'm using, its version of web3 is the 0.x version:

`> web3.version
{
  api: "0.20.1",
  ethereum: "0x3f",
  network: "2429",
  node: "Geth/TestNode1/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.3",`

So is TypeScript tripping over its own typings/specification files, or is it actually communicating with geth to see that this function does not exist, and I would need to go to a later geth that uses web3 1.x (if it even exists yet)? Thanks for any help or guidance.